# HTML does not recognize external JS file function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a simple JS function where I click on a button, and the background changes into the color of that button. I have used an external JS file but even though I have used the function, it shows this error :'changecolor' is defined but never used.
here's the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>JavaScript Background Color Switcher</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
        <span onclick="changecolor('grey')" class="button" id="grey"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('white')" class="button" id="white"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('blue')" class="button" id="blue"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('yellow')" class="button" id="yellow"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html> 

JS file:
function changecolor (id) {
  document.body.style.background = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
}
```

Comment: hey man the innerHTML you are referring to is empty thats why the chrome producing any effects try adding Grey as text in span with id grey and so on!!

Comment: @BhavyaSingh can you write me the example code?

Comment: First make sure that your external js file is loaded successfully or not. You can do it by  checking in console of chrome dev tools.

Comment: @dorian check my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>JavaScript Background Color Switcher</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
        <span onclick="changecolor('grey')" class="button" id="grey"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('white')" class="button" id="white"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('blue')" class="button" id="blue"></span>
        <span onclick="changecolor('yellow')" class="button" id="yellow"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html> 

JS file:
function changecolor (id) {
  document.body.style.background = id;
}
```

now tell me if it works or not :)

Comment: yessss it works thank you man, but can I hide those grey...text so it doesnt appear in by buttons?

Comment: @dorian now you can customize the buttons without affecting js

Comment: Hey man another question, how to write the same code with query selector?

Comment: document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function btn (id) {
  document.body.style.background = id
})

Comment: I wrote this one with the same html (I deleted the onclick parts) but it doesnt work

Comment: @dorian let me write another answer with query selector one

Comment: @dorian check my new answer it describes this implementation

Answer (score 0):

Move script tag into the head section. Or at least put function declaration before its usage (move script tag to the very top of body).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use a script tag at the end of the body where you are including the JS file. And to consume the functions of the JS file you should use them bellow the include of the file. This is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag's greater than mark is in the wrong place.
Move it right after  and

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>JavaScript Background Color Switcher</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
        <div id="switch"><!--dont delete this div its here to avoid js to select all elements with class button -->
          <span class="button" id="grey"></span>
          <span class="button" id="white"></span>
          <span class="button" id="blue"></span>
          <span class="button" id="yellow"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
function changecolor(id) {
  document.body.style.background = id;
}
var rootElem = document.querySelector("#switch");
var buttonArr = rootElem.querySelectorAll(".button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttonArr.length; i++){
   buttonArr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       changecolor(buttonArr[i].id);
   }
}
```

Just drop the name or hex of the color in the id of the button and add as many as you want

> Warning Dont remove div with id switch and dont alter the class of the
>   buttons used for the switching color